# C++ DLL char paramteters

Tags: c++, c, string, dll

I want to call this c++ function from a C program. I want to use the char* errorMessage to return a error message. When I do a **return errorMessage** in the code i get the char pointer in my C application after the return. But if i try to `errorMessage = SafeStringHeap(string("File name was empty."));` I always get a Null Pointer in my C application.

I tried to call my function with the following text in the c application:

```
char* errorMessage = NULL;
TAFMessage = (*TAFParseMessageFile)(NULL, errorMessage);
```

The functions:

```
static char* SafeStringHeap(string message)
{
    //Save string on the heap
    char * cstr = new char[message.length() + 1];
    strcpy_s(cstr, message.length() + 1, message.c_str());

    return cstr;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) const char* TAFParseMessageFile(const char* fileName, char* errorMessage)
{
    if (fileName == NULL)
    {
        errorMessage = SafeStringHeap(string("File name was empty."));
        return errorMessage;
    }

    return NULL;    // TODO: set errorMessage
}
```

Comment: Why do you pass in an error message? What do you think will happen to the memory allocated in your SafeStringHeap function? Who will deallocate it? And when? Maybe it's better to pass in an actual char array so you can write your error message to it?

Comment: You mean the following?:

char errorMessage[100];
TAFMessage = (*TAFParseMessageFile)(NULL, errorMessage);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subject to the other concerns raised above. Try changing your errorMessage argument to a char ** (pointer to a char pointer) and then do:

```
*errorMessage = SafeStringHeap(...)
```

And when calling the function pass &errorMessage

Comment: Because when ever you want to manipulate the value of an argument, i.e. Using it as an OUT variable, you need to add additional layer of indirection. Think for example of: calling a function using an int type, if you want the function to project a manipulation of the int argument back to the caller, then you must pass the address of that int, so the worker function can place the new value into the caller place holder for that arg.

Comment: Btw, if your question was answered, then it is recommended to mark it as Answered by accepting the answer.